# How to drag a component with animation in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to drag a component whose css has transform animation.
But it could not work.
The component just move according to animation and could not be dragged.
Is there any way to achieve the drag function?

```js
import * as React from "react";
import {
  theComponent
} from "../style.css";
import Draggable from "react-draggable";

class DragMe extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Draggable
        axis="both"
        handle=".handle"
        defaultPosition={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
        position={null}
        grid={[25, 25]}
        scale={1}
        onStart={this.handleStart}
        onDrag={this.handleDrag}
        onStop={this.handleStop}
      >
        <div className={theComponent + " handle"}>
          <p>Drag Me!</p>
        </div>
      </Draggable>
    );
  }
}
```

```css
. theComponent{
  animation: moveAnimation 3.5s infinite;
}

@keyframes moveAnimation {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translate(-200%, 20%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-200%, 25%);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `@keyframes moveAnimation` styles `transform` broke inline styles `transform` on `.handle`. You must use only css animatioin or Draggable. Might you can add `defaultPosition={{ x: 200, y: 20 }}` and remove `@keyframes moveAnimation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change css animation from  `transform` to `top, left`, inline styles `transform` will be work and dragged. Try rewrite css like this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-microservice-x43hg)

```
.theComponent {
  position: relative;
  animation: moveAnimation 3.5s infinite;
}
@keyframes moveAnimation {
  0%,
  100% {
    top: 5px;
  }
  50% {
     top: 0px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! It works! Thank you so much!